# How to refresh multiple screens on a single button click MVC C#

Tags: c#

Hope everyone is well.
I am dealing with a multiplayer system and having a problem with the real time refresh. I've tried, metatags, JS function:set intervals for a div, Ajax refresh based on success,.... They all work on that particular screen.

So example if Jack, Barney, Nick and Mary are online playing this game.... When Mary plays, her screen will refresh/update divs accordingly.... However on the other 3 player's screens nothing will happen.

I need a REFRESH/UPDATE of a div to take place when a click is made by any user, this refresh/update must happen ON MULTIPLE SCREENS (any user who is on that page must be able to view the most recent and up to date set of data)

If you have any information on how to go about doing this, please let me know! :)

Comment: It'll be much easier for people to help you if you show some code and explain what you've already tried.

Comment: look at server sent events, web sockets or polling.

Comment: SignalR is what you're after

Answer (score 2):

In other words, you need the server to notify clients of events. With ASP.NET, you should use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for that. It uses the modern WebSockets API if available, and gracefully falls back to other techniques like polling in browsers that don't support WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example of SignalR 2 using with MVC 5 here:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5